# C# populate DataGrid with List<List<string>>?

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid, datasource

Let's say I have a DataGrid in WinForms (C#).

I want to populate it but my data is in this format:

```
List<List<string>> datas;
```

For simple test I add values:

```
List<List<string>> ds = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> row1 = new List<string>();
row1.Add("col1");
row1.Add("col2");
row1.Add("col3");
ds.Add(row1);
```

When I add `ds` as datasouce for the grid it displays something I don't understand:

```
grid.DataSource = ds;
```

[image]

I tried also with LINQ, but did not succeed, datagrid is empty. How can I solve this?

I'd do it with or without LINQ if that is faster than manually iterating and populating with for loops.

Comment: First of all you're adding `ds` as datasource but you're not assigning values other than new List<List<string>>
Then, I am not sure it can handle a list of lists. 
You might want to have your own object   
`ds = new List<SomeObject>();`
`ds.Add(new SomeObject("col1", "col2");`

Comment: Is it possible to change the data format to a class instead?

Comment: @Keelah, sorry, one line was left out, corrected.

Comment: @AlvinAlmodal: not really - with classes I know how to deal :)

Comment: But inner list can be changed to Dictionary<string,string> where first string is column second is value. Does it help? (List<Dictionary<string,string>>)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code found [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable) to suit your needs;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
  list.Add(new List<string>()
  {
    "Row 1, Col 1",
    "Row 1, Col 2",
    "Row 1, Col 3",
  });
  list.Add(new List<string>()
  {
    "Row 2, Col 1",
    "Row 2, Col 2",
    "Row 2, Col 3",
  });
  list.Add(new List<string>()
  {
    "Row 3, Col 1",
    "Row 3, Col 2",
    "Row 3, Col 3",
  });

  DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}

static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<List<string>> list)
{

  DataTable table = new DataTable();

  int columns = 0;
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    if (item.Count > columns)
    {
      columns = item.Count;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
  {
    table.Columns.Add();
  }

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    DataRow new_row = table.NewRow();
    foreach(var col in item)
    {
      new_row[item.IndexOf(col)] = col;
    }
    table.Rows.Add(new_row);
  }

  return table;
}
```

Which returns the datagrid as per below

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I'd prefer the DataSource approach, I think that is faster. This grid should handle thousands of lines.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, I don't follow. `dataGridView1.DataSource = table;` is using DataSource, and testing this against 10,000 rows takes ~38ms.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. One more thing: creating a DataTable manually and then use it as DataSource is better in performance than manually filling up the grid itself?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so as it's an extra step in the process, but I'm not aware of a direct method of binding `List<List<T>>` to a grid DataSource